# amTimeAgo in angular-moment make crazy calcs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, momentjs, angular-moment

So I'm trying to use directive amTimeAgo of momment JS in Angular, like this:

```
<span class="work-duration" ng-bind="item.startedAt | amTimeAgo: item.finishedAt: 'years' "></span>
```

I'm usting angular-moment (https://github.com/urish/angular-moment)

well, I want to show an date like, from: 02/09/2013 - to: 02/09/2015 - (2 years) or in different cases, 1 year and 3 months

Okay, in some cases the directive makes crazy calc,

some dates like this:

01/05/2012 - 30/09/2012 results in (3 years) why? Someone have any experiencie with this directive?

I tried to use the amFrom, but appears that this directive is not available in angularMoment,

in pure momment.JS:

```
var a = moment([2007, 0, 28]);
var b = moment([2007, 0, 29]);
a.from(b) // "a day ago"
```

Probably, this "from" method should works better than amTimeAgo.

Obs: in console, I got a lot of warnings about the finishedAt value:

**angular-moment: Ignoring unsupported value for preprocess: 2015-10-01T03:00:00.000+0000**

Comment: seems like you want the difference filter

Comment: the Difference filter, returns in miliseconds ://

Comment: it has arguments also...look at example output for `days`

Comment: Please edit your question to show how `startedAt` and `finishedAt` are wired up in your controller.  Are the strings? `Date` objects? `moment` objects?  Hint: It's probably a parsing issue (30 months instead of 30 days)